# Where do I ask a question about my resume?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

On which site should I ask this question?  Is there one?

I will soon be in the following situation:  I was in a PhD program, but due to various problems I was unable to complete the PhD and instead ended up with a Master's.  Should I list both the completed Master's degree and the unfinished PhD on my resume?

Comment: **NOT** Programmers.

Comment: It *might* potentially be on-topic for [this site proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/30887/the-workplace?referrer=t0qzW5ESkS-JS6wd42Y-3w2) once it gets off the ground (although with the name change/focus shift/proposal merge it appears it may no longer be). Alternately, [this proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/13418/interviewing-recruiting?referrer=5BU2otyXrCnfq7IcDS4gNw2) is still in an earlier stage, but seems a better fit.

Comment: @Jim While it's not definitive, that comment looks like an answer, and might be the best answer that exists.

Comment: Ugh, we keep getting proposals from people who want to be able to ask questions like this, and then once the sites actually start, people decide that questions like this aren't a good fit and therefore aren't allowed. Thus the cycle starts over again, propose a new site, blah blah. Can't we just end the charade already? Either convince the existing sites like Programmers to allow these questions if so many community members want them, or give up already and ask a career counselor.

Comment: @Cody It seems like you have identified an important piece of the Stack Exchange circle of life.  If your assertion is true, questions like this are necessary for the bootstrapping process.

Comment: The bootstrapping process happens over on [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/). Convincing the Programmers mods happens over on [Programmers Meta](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/). I'm not sure what about this discussion is necessary or important.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of Area51 proposals that might accept this question. First is [The Workplace](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/30887/the-workplace?referrer=t0qzW5ESkS-JS6wd42Y-3w2) (formerly Professional Matter, formerly The Water Cooler). Second is [Interviewing & Recruiting](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/13418/interviewing-recruiting?referrer=5BU2otyXrCnfq7IcDS4gNw2).

Unfortunately, it seems the focus of these is more on the *other* end of the process (already having a job, or *doing* the interviewing/hiring), but I think it's the closest you could get to a StackExchange site where such a question would be on topic (at least everyone there is there to discuss related topics, and has the knowledge to be able to answer your question, regardless of whether they deem it "on-topic").